# How to Install .IPK file in LG WebOS TV?

Tags: build, webos, lg

I have created an Application using WebOS IDE and generated a `.IPK` build now I want to share this `.IPK` file to other developers for testing purposes. So
 **how can I install this `.IPK` build to other WebOs Tv without using WebOS IDE or WebOS CLI ?**

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately LG removed any option to run or install applications from the USB (for security reasons). The only way to install an IPK is using Webos IDE (eclipse) or the CLI tools (Novacom and Ares) and always activating the development mode first.

Comment: That's not true. It's still possible to install app on USB but developer mode must be active.

Comment: Can you link the source? As far I know only Digital Signage models is able install from USB

Comment: source: ME. I did it many times. ares utility has an option to install on usb.

Comment: Maybe you could describe the whole process (commands, tv model, sw versión, etc) as an answer and share it with the community :) Best Regards